# Best way to give action feedback to user with Polymer 1.0

Tags: javascript, user-interface, polymer

It may be a trivial problem, but I am wondering what is the best way to notify that user that the action he intended has been done, or that an error happened.

An ugly way of doing this, for explanation sakes, would be an alert popup. But how to do this with Polymer and MD?
Do this feedback need to be included in your element behaviour, like a button flushing to redish color instead of the regular color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Snackbars provide lightweight feedback about an operation by showing a brief message at the bottom of the screen. Snackbars can contain an action. https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/snackbars-toasts.html#

[image: Snackbar example]

The reference implementation in Polymer is called `paper-toast`. https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-toast